# How can I find out the model code for my Google mini

Tags: google-search-appliance

We are experiencing some problems with our google mini and I need to know what model we're using as referenced here http://code.google.com/apis/searchappliance/documentation/52/troubleshooting/Designing_Search_Solution.html#Queueing

Our google mini is racked and the label seems to be underneath it, so it's not easy to find out this way. Does anyone know how I can find out the model number - either though the web interface, or point me to any more documentation on the matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it doesn't appear to be possible to access this information through the interface so we had to unrack the Google mini to find this out.

I'd still be interested in an answer if anyone else has been able to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

A simple search on images can help you.
http://www.semyj.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/google-mini-gsa8.jpg

- Google mini:Blue 1U rack mount
- 1001: Yellow 2U rack mount
- 7007: Yellow 2U rack mount (black google sticker)
- 5005: 5x1001
- 8008: 12x1001

1001, 5005 and 8008 are now discontinued.